# Gremlin: Blazegraph Remote

Tags: java, multithreading, graph, gremlin, blazegraph

I am trying to get the pipeline up and running with the following setup:

- Blazegraph 2.1.1 (remote)
- Tinkerpop 2 (bigdata-blueprints 2.0.0, BlazeGraph-Gremlin 1.0.0, bigdata-core 2.0.0)
- Language: Java

I have been able to use the Blueprints API for creating and deleting vertices and edges. I would like to stick to Tinkerpop as much as possible for all graph operations. I was unable to find APIs for:

1. threaded transactions via `ThreadedTransactionalGraph`.
2. traversals using `GremlinPipeline`.

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a timeline on when TP3 for the remote version of Blazegraph would be available?
2. Are there any plans of supporting the following in the near future?

   a. Blueprints `ThreadedTransactionalGraph`

   b. `GremlinPipeline` API
3. What are the suggested alternatives available for 2a and 2b?

---

I have tried the `getFeatures` function the graph is providing and it's getting the following list:

```
supportsDuplicateEdges: true
supportsSelfLoops: true
supportsSerializableObjectProperty: false
supportsBooleanProperty: true
supportsDoubleProperty: true
supportsFloatProperty: true
supportsIntegerProperty: true
supportsPrimitiveArrayProperty: true
supportsUniformListProperty: true
supportsMixedListProperty: true
supportsLongProperty: true
supportsMapProperty: false
supportsStringProperty: true
ignoresSuppliedIds: false
isPersistent: true
isWrapper: false
supportsIndices: true
supportsVertexIndex: false
supportsEdgeIndex: false
supportsKeyIndices: true
supportsVertexKeyIndex: true
supportsEdgeKeyIndex: true
supportsEdgeIteration: true
supportsVertexIteration: true
supportsEdgeRetrieval: true
supportsVertexProperties: true
supportsEdgeProperties: true
supportsTransactions: false
supportsThreadedTransactions: false
```

My major concern here is that I am not allowed to work with `GremlinPipeline` while querying in Blazegraph with remote.

I have an existing API running on OrientDB and I want to migrate to Blazegraph. Do I have to change all my read stuff (Gremlin queries) in order to use Blazegraph or is there a way to use Tinkerpop 2 along with `GremlinPipeline`?

Comment: I haven't used Blazegraph, but isn't this what you're looking for? https://github.com/blazegraph/tinkerpop3

Comment: As Jason pointed out I think you looking for the [gremlin])(https://github.com/blazegraph/tinkerpop3) plugin for blazegraph. I have used it and I can confirm it supports Threaded Transactions.

Comment: Sounds like you should add that as an answer @FilipeTeixeira :)

Comment: I think that it is worth clarifying that this question contains a confusion of TinkerPop 2.x and 3.x concepts. There is no "Blueprints" project, or a "Pipeline API". Looking at the code, BlazeGraph implements the TinkerPop Graph Structure API (formerly Blueprints) which should enable it to take advantage of the Traversal API (formerly Pipes - i.e. Pipeline API).

Answer (score 1):

As Jason pointed out with regards to Tinkerpop 3 you should look at [this](https://github.com/blazegraph/tinkerpop3) plugin.

However, in my comment I was wrong about it supporting threaded transactions. Blazegraph using TP3 does not at the moment support `ThreadedTranactions`, but does support `ConcurrentAccess` as well as Tinkerpop Transactions. Even though threads have to wait for each other to complete.

```
BlazeGraphEmbedded graph = BlazeGraphFactory.open("test.jnl");
graph.features();
```

returns:

```
FEATURES
GraphFeatures
-- Computer: false
-- Persistence: true
-- ConcurrentAccess: true
-- Transactions: true
-- ThreadedTransactions: false
```

With regards to the status of this support on Blazegraph TP2 or TP3 you should raise an issue with them.